# on_open websocket function isn't being called

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to stream stock data from Polygon.io but the websocket app won't call my on_open function.
Code sample; [[screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9KfQ.png)

```
import websocket, json 
from secrety import *

socket = 'wss://socket.polygon.io/stocks'

def on_open(ws):

    print("OPEN")

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_open=on_open)

ws.run_forever()
```

I'm trying to connect to a Polygon.io websocket to stream stock info but I can't get my websocket app to work. I'm new to this so I'm not really sure what I'm doing. I'm on an M1 Mac and my code files are in a virtual en.
I just want OPEN to be printed to make sure the function is being called but when I run the file, nothing happens (as in on_open isn't being called)

I can connect to Polygons websocket through terminal commands, although I'm not sure if that even matters.
Thanks for any input

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Oops, just now realizing that I shouldn't upload photos